# Serverless Framework, how can I get the final serverless.yml version (after load all variables) before deploy to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless to deploy some lambdas to AWS. I have some environment variables that are loaded in the `serverless.yml` before deploy to the server.

What is the command to `mount` and display the `serverless.yml` before deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `serverless print`, which will print it to your CLI.

[docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/print/)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I can help!

Comment: do y know the answer for this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023000/how-to-protect-whitelist-only-1-endpoint-of-an-aws-api-gateway-trough-serverle ??